# Java - How to know what key is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

I am developing this application, it is a ball bouncing around. But i want to add purpoise of the application. So I want the user to be able to move a pad around, to prevent the ball from touching the wall. So I have got this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainframeTwo extends JPanel implements Runnable{

Color color = Color.red;
int dia = 60;
int diaPad = 120;
long delay = 20;
private int x = 120;
private int y = 340;
private int xx = 120;
private int yy = 670;
private int dx = 6;
private int dy = 7;
private int dxx = 6;
boolean leftKey = false;
boolean rightKey = false;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setColor(color); 
    g.fillOval(x,y,60,60);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(xx,yy,120,15);

}

public void run() {
    while(isVisible()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted");
        }
        moveBall();
        repaint();
    }
}

public void moveBall() {
    if(x + dx < 0 || x + dia + dx > getWidth()) {
        dx *= -1;
        color = getColorOne();
    }
    if(y + dy < 0 || y + dia + dy > getHeight()) {
        dy *= -1;
        color = getColorOne();
    }
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

public void movePadRight() {
        if(xx + dxx < 0 || xx + diaPad + dxx > getWidth()) {
             dxx *= -1;
        }
        xx += dxx;
}
public void movePadLeft() {
        if(xx + dxx < 0 || xx + diaPad + dxx > getWidth()) {
             dxx *= -1;
        }
        xx += dxx;
}

private Color getColorOne() {
    int rval = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    int gval = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    int bval = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return new Color(rval, gval, bval);
}


private void start() {
    while(!isVisible()) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(25);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
    thread.start();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            MainframeTwo test = new MainframeTwo();

            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

            panel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

                @Override
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
              System.out.println("Released" + e.getKeyChar());
          }

                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Pressed " + e.getKeyChar());

                }
            });

            panel.setFocusable(true);
            panel.requestFocusInWindow();

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(test);
            frame.setSize(640, 960);
            Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            test.start();

        }

    };

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);

}
}
```

Terrible formatting, I know.
But anyways, I want to be able to have a if() function that will trigger if the key A and S is pressed. I dont know f that is possible. If it is not possible, please tell me a way to trigger movePadLeft and Right, when the keys A and S is pressed.

Comment: Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and save yourself the heart of trying to figure out why your `KeyListener` won't respond

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's responding and the code is up and working by now...

Comment: 1) For Swing, typically use key bindings over the AWT based, lower level, `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details on how to use them.  2) `Thread.sleep(delay);`  Use a Swing `Timer`.  Don't block the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: @CarlA It is responding "now", the moment you add another focusable control or the window loses focus for some reason, it won't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

```
if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        //A pressed...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I would call my function movePadRight(); in the if I would get this error:

MainFrameTwo.java:129: non-static method movePadRight() cannot be referenced from a static context
                            movePadRight();
                            ^

Comment: You cannot use instance methods from static context, i.e. your static main method. You could instantiate MainframeTwo and invoke movePadRight() in this instance context.

Comment: @CarlA Often my `main` method in a class C has just one statement `new C().runMain(args);` and then I put all the good stuff in a `runMain` method that is _not_ `static`.  That gives you a `C` object from which you can keep local variables, call instance methods, etc.

Comment: @ajb Thanks that makes sense... Will finish the code tomorrow.

Comment: -1, Don't use a KeyListener!!! Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`.

Comment: @camickr generally, we shouldn't mix swing with awt.

Comment: KeyListeners are used with AWT because there is no other option. JPanel is Swing. This is a Swing related question, that is why Key Bindings should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean to keep track of whether each key you care about is pressed. Set those booleans in the keyPressed() and keyReleased() methods. Check the value of those booleans in the movePad() functions and do the correct thing.